# Does the jruby-rack servlet container support PUT/DELETE?

Tags: tomcat, jrubyonrails, warbler, jruby-rack

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app as a WAR using Warbler. I have it running in Tomcat 6 and it seems to be running fine. However, all of my `PUT` and `DELETE` requests are getting rejected with a `403 (Forbidden)`.

From what I've been able to gather, the default Tomcat install on Debian/Ubuntu has these methods disabled via:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>readonly</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I've tried setting this to `false` in my `/etc/tomcat6/web.xml` but no dice. I wonder if I have to do something similar to the `jruby-rack` servlet container packaged by Warbler in my WAR? If so, how would I go about this?

If not, why would Tomcat be rejecting all of the `PUT`s and `DELETE`s being sent to my Rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for extra detail, here is the relevant bug on jruby-rack:

https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack/issues/105

It looks like a fix is in progress at the time of this writing.

Comment: Looks like this was patched in https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack/commit/c42ee20e3d15b6c4a8cf316cafcf3bd5410cdfca. Haven't had a chance to try this out yet though.

Comment: jruby-rack **1.1.6** is released fixing this regression, alternatively using the servlet operation mode would have worked as a workaround for this case thus I've added another anwser just in case someone gets stucked with a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. 
I changed the version of the jruby-rack gem from 1.1.5 to 1.1.4 and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

for the record for issues like these - specific to the `RackFilter` one can always try using the servlet operation mode as a workaround, just remove the filter declaration (and mapping) and declare and map the `RackServlet` :

```
<!--
<filter>
  <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.jruby.rack.RackFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>-->

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>RackServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.jruby.rack.RackServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RackServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in case you're using warbler copy the *web.xml.erb* into your *config* directory:

```
cp [GEM_HOME]/gems/warbler-1.3.4/web.xml.erb config
```